# using JQuery .not( ) to fade out all divs apart from the selected and it's children

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout, children

I currently have a grid of images and each image has a hover function that changes the opacity of a div. So the image is a background image, and the information is a div within grid-item.

```
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="image-rollover">
        <div class="title">
          Image title text
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="info">
        Image information text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I've got a function that makes each grid item disappear apart from the one that is clicked:

```
$(".grid-item").click(function() {
  var selected = this;
  $(selected).children(".image-rollover").css("opacity", "1");
  $(function() {
    $('.grid div').not(selected).fadeOut(200);
  });
});
```

I would like all the images apart from the clicked one to disappear and I want the rollover state of that clicked image to remain. I've got the first half, but the hover state disappears despite me setting the CSS to 1.

I think it's something to do with .not(), and it seems that .not() doesn't include all the child elements within that div??

Can anyone suggest something that selects all divs apart from the selected and ALL it's child elements?

Answer (score 3):

`.grid div` matches all the `div`s, including those *inside* your `grid-item`.

If you match only on the direct children, it will work as intended.

```
$(".grid-item").click(function() {
  var selected = this;
  $('.grid>div').not(selected).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Note how I replaced `.grid div` by `.grid > div`.
See [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcsdvj72/1/).

I have also removed the anonymous function inside your click handler, which is unnecessary given the context you have posted.